# SQL Query for lowest time rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, datetime

I have a table with one DateTime column. I want to find the rows with lowest time which their times are more than a variable myTime.
How can I do that?
What kind of index will increase the performance?

Comment: Time only, the date and/or day of the week means nothing?

Comment: In SQL Server DataTime is a kind which has both date and time in itself.

Comment: I think you mean DateTime, not DataTime.

Comment: How many rows do you want?  Do you want all rows greater than myTime, but ordered so the most recent are at the top of the list?

Comment: No Just with the Lowest time above myTime.

Comment: @Shayan: What if there is are two equal lowest?

Comment: for example if we have three times 17:55 17:55 and 17:56 and myTime is 17:54 then the result should contain two 17:55 s.

Comment: Does your table only have one column? You don't have a primary key?

Comment: This is the column that must be considered. Other rows as well as a primary key is also available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using TOP (SQL Server 2000+)

---

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM TABLE t
 WHERE t.date_time_col = (SELECT TOP 1
                                 x.date_time_col
                            FROM TABLE x
                           WHERE CONVERT(hh, x.date_time_col, 8) < @myTime
                        ORDER BY x.date_time_col)
```

### Using MIN

---

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM TABLE t
 WHERE t.date_time_col = (SELECT MIN(x.date_time_col)
                            FROM TABLE x
                           WHERE CONVERT(hh, x.date_time_col, 8) < @myTime)
```

Neither will use an index, assuming one exists on the DATETIME column, because of the use of a function - the data type is being changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DateTime1
FROM Table1
WHERE DateTime1 = (
    SELECT MIN(DateTime1)
    FROM Table1
    WHERE DateTime1 > @myTime);
```

or:

```
SELECT T1.DateTime1
FROM Table1 AS T1
JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(DateTime1) AS DateTime1
    FROM Table1
    WHERE DateTime1 > @myTime) AS T2
ON T1.DateTime1 = T2.DateTime1;
```

Run both to see which is fastest. Use an index on DateTime1.

Test data to check it works:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (DateTime1 NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO Table1 (DateTime1) VALUES
('2010-02-01 17:53'),
('2010-02-01 17:55'),
('2010-02-01 17:55'),
('2010-02-01 17:56');
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this then...

```
DECLARE @temp datetime

SET @temp = (SELECT GETDATE())

Select myCol from MyTable where MyColWithDate IN (SELECT top 1 MyCol, MyCol2 FROM MyTable WHERE MyColWithDate > @temp ORDER BY MyColWithDate ASC)
```

or I'd probably go with the MIN

```
Select myCol from MyTable where MyColWithDate IN (SELECT MIN(MycolWithDAte) FROM MyTable WHERE MyColWithDate > @temp GROUP BY MyColWithDate)
```

Comment: But this is inefficient. Any built-in method?

Comment: Have you looked at the OVER clause? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Comment: And why do you say it's inefficient?  The subquery is executed one time and returns one value which is then used for one more query.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @temp datetime

SET @temp = (SELECT GETDATE())

SELECT MyCol, MyCol2 FROM MyTable WHERE MyColWithDate > @temp ORDER BY MyColWithDate ASC
```

Regarding the index it depends can you tell us more info about what you are trying to do.
Otherwise you could index MyColWithDate for the above example.

Comment: I want all of them with the LOWEST time.